# -file option error when exporting an x509 certificate using windows terminal

Tags: java, windows, certificate, export, keytool

I am in the Java bin in Windows terminal. I entered the following code:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin>keytool -export -alias me2 -file "Desktop\me.cert"
```

Received the following error:

> keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Desktop\me.cert (The
>   system cannot find the path specified)

Just as a note, I already tried without the **""** marks, and also tried using "`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\me.cert`" as my file location. I also tried manually creating the cert file in the specified `-file` location before running that line of code. Non of those have worked.

Comment: I also made sure to run the terminal with administrator privileges. This did not work either.

Comment: I would try something that does not contain a space in the path like "c:\me.cert"

Comment: According to [this page](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html) the command should look like `keytool -export -alias mydomain -file mydomain.crt -keystore keystore.jks`. I don't see the `keystore` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to store the certificate in the actual `Desktop`, and not a folder called 'Desktop', you command would like this:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin> keytool -export -alias me2 -file "C:\Users\USER_NAME\Desktop\me.cert" -keystore KEYSTORE_FILE -storepass KEYSTORE_PASSWORD